# Configurable product image is not showing in Magento order review page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9.2.1.

The problem I am facing is that configurable product image is not showing in order review page but it is working fine for simple product.

I go to this page `frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review.phtml`

```
<div class="order-review" id="checkout-review-load">
    <!-- Content loaded dynamically -->
</div>
```

I didn't get the template page for order review page. How can I find this page or find how to show configurable product image in order review page?

Answer (score 0):

By default, on the review page the items are rendered using itemrenderer as defined in the checkout layout xml: **app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml**:

```
<checkout_onepage_review translate="label">
    ...
    <block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
    ....
```

So your item renderer file is
**checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml** as far as you don't change it via layout updates.

If you want to handle configurable products differently you have to specify your custom itemrenderer using **layout updates**.

You can change the item renderer via your modules *etc/config.xml* defining an layout update file or your themes *local.xml* file. Your local.xml of your own theme should be located at *app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/layout/local.xml*.

The layout update should look like this:

```
<checkout_onepage_review>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>PATH/TO/YOUR/TEMPLATE/item.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_review>
```

You can also specify your own cart_item_renderer_configuarble block. With your block and your custom renderer template you can change the handling of configurable products in your review page.

Comment: Are you really guessing or do you know for sure?

Comment: No, there is no any clue for changing image in this page. I already checked this page

Comment: @Prince added more info about layout updates and how to specify your own configurable product renderer inside the review page.

Comment: @Prince can you please update your question and add the code you tried out?